# Add custom to field to CMS page based on template in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cms, page-layouts, fieldsets

I have several custom fields I added to my CMS pages but I only want them to show up on the backend if the admin user selects a specific template. For example, the text field "doctor name" would only show after "doctor" template was selected under layout->Design

New fields are added through the cms_page_form.xml and InstallSchema.php